# How can I prevent input special character with limit length in android kotlin?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-edittext

I have problem with limit length. like this code below can prevent input special characters, but cannot limit length of input.

```
val filter: InputFilter
    get() = InputFilter { source, start, end, dest, dstart, dend ->
        if (source != null && BLOCK_CHARACTER.contains(("" + source))) {
            return@InputFilter ""
        }
        for (i in start until end) {
            if (!Character.isLetter(source[i]) || !Character.isLetterOrDigit(source[i])) {
                if (source[i].toString() == "@") {
                } else {
                    if (Character.isUnicodeIdentifierPart(source[i])) {
                        return@InputFilter null
                    } else if (Character.isSpaceChar(source[i]) || Character.isWhitespace(source[i])) {
                        return@InputFilter " "
                    }
                    return@InputFilter ""
                }
            }
        }

        return@InputFilter null
    }
```

So how can we prevent input special character with limit length?

Comment: why don't you use android:maxLength

Comment: I used already, but it's not work.

Comment: you can try this:else if (Character.isSpaceChar(source[i]) || Character.isWhitespace(source[i]) || dend>(maxLength,eg:10)) {
                        return@InputFilter " "
                    }